# Can't attach any database to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Ok this is what I get:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>   Additional information: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(error not found) while attempting to open or create the physical fife 'C: \Program Fifes (x86) \Microsoft SQL Server \MSSQL.1 \MSSQL \Data \MyCompany.mdf. (MIcrosoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

I have already reinstalled SQL Server 2012, and it still doesn't work. Before this problem I tried to attach the AdventureWorks database and insert some command (I have deleted it) and since then I keep having this problem. I am new to SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: There seem to be some typographical errors in your error-text. The path is missing a number I think. MSSQL11? Please confirm SQLServer version.  Also you have "fifes" not "files".

Comment: MSSQL.1 that's what it says...And yes fife is a typo.

Comment: If you open the database in SSMS and look at its properties, what does it say there for the path?

Comment: This: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a permission issue. The account under which the SQL Server process is running has no write permission to the programs folder. Either you add those permissions to the account running the SQL Server service or you attach your database at a location where the SQL Server service account has read/write rights.

See [this DBA Stackexchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/22250) for the same issue.

Answer (score 18):

if you use SSMS try to execute it as Administrator.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  UAC has a lot to answer for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .mdf file is not in "Read-only" mode. If its in "Read-only" mode, select its properties and untick "Read-only" and click OK and then attach the file. It surely works